# Use standard deviation as a variable in a correlation test?

Tags: self-study, correlation

I have several "lanes" (i.e. Shanghai to LA, Bejing to LA, Shanghai to Georgia, and Beijing to Georgia). On these lane I normally ship widgets by boat. However, if a shipment is delayed by several days, I have to ship widgets by plane so I don't shut down a manufacturing plant.

I have a data set that contains the number of days every shipment on every lane took. I used this data set to calculate the standard deviation of transit days for each lane.

I have another data set that contains the amount of money I spent flying widgets on each lane.

I want to run a correlation test between the standard deviation of transit days on a lane and the amount money spent flying widgets on that lane. I.e. does increased transit variability result in lots of extra money spent flying widgets and, if so, how strongly are the two correlated.

My questions is: Is a correlation test valid if one of the variables is a standard deviation? I'm concerned this might be like taking an average of standard deviations which I know is a big no no.